# limit of f(x) as x approaches c is 0 and limit of [f(x)g(x)] as x approaches c is 1. Prove that limit of g(x) as x approaches c does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

Lets say that $\lim \limits_{x \to c}$  $f(x) = 0$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to c}$  $f(x)g(x) = 1$

How would you prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to c}$  $g(x)$ Does Not Exist?

I hear that it can be done through a proof by contradiction, but I do not understand how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prove that $P$ implies $Q$ by contradiction, then you assume the negation of $Q$ (i.e., assume that $Q$ is false) and use that to contradict something that follows from $P$.

In this situation, suppose that 
$$
\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = a,
$$
for some $a$.  (By negating the conclusion, we are assuming that this limit exists.  In other words, it has a value.)  Since you have assumed that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to c$, you can calculate:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to c} \bigl( f(x) \cdot g(x) \bigr) 
&= \Bigl( \lim_{x \to c} f(x) \Bigr) \cdot 
\Bigl( \lim_{x \to c} g(x) \Bigr) \\
&= 0 \cdot a \\
&= 0,
\end{align}
contradicting the assumption that
$$
\lim_{x \to c} \bigl( f(x) \cdot g(x) \bigr) = 1.
$$

---

Intuitively, in words, if $f(x)$ gets smaller and smaller as $x$ approaches $c$, then in order for the product $f(x) g(x)$ to approach $1$ at the same time, then $g(x)$ must get bigger and bigger (not approach a limiting value).  Here's a simple example:
$$
f(x) = x - c \qquad\text{and}\qquad g(x) = \frac{1}{x-c}.
$$